# React component toggle method causing `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.` error

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to write an onClick method that toggles a child element, but my current implementation results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I'm unsure of how my setup needs to be changed to not cause this infinite loop. Here's how my container component is setup:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const NestedProperty = styled.div`
  margin-left: 2rem;
`;

const ParentContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const NestedContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

class SideMenuContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        active: false
    };
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log("toggle click!")
    this.setState({active : !this.state.active});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.active == true){
      return (
        <ParentContainer>
          <p onClick={this.handleClick()}>{this.props.parentName}</p>
          <NestedContainer>
            {this.props.properties.map(propertyElement => {
              return (
                <NestedProperty onClick={() => { this.props.changeInfoList(propertyElement.name, propertyElement.data_type, propertyElement.app_keys.join(', '))}} >
                  {propertyElement.name}
                </NestedProperty>
              );
            })}
          </NestedContainer>
        </ParentContainer>
      );    
    }

    else {
      return (
        <ParentContainer>
          <p onClick={this.handleClick()}>{this.props.parentName}</p>
        </ParentContainer>
      );
    }

  }
}

export default SideMenuContainer;
```

In essence, what I'm trying to do is have it so that whenever the `parentName` is clicked, its child (`NestedProperty`) div toggles on and off. If the `active` property in state is `true`, the child `NestedProperty` div is rendered under the Parent, if its `false`, only the parentName is rendered.

What's causing this infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the function `handleClick` wrongly. Change it to

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

and with that you need to bind the function, you can do that with the fat arrow notation

```
handleClick = () => {
    console.log("toggle click!")
    this.setState({active : !this.state.active});
  }
```

Comment: Ah I see. After making those changes, the page renders successfully, but clicking doesn't do anything, and the console gives a warning saying "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state."

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not bind properly with 'this'. Use it like below

```
    onClick = { () => this.handleClick() }
```